# Составить условие php из текстовых частей массива

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток. Хотелось бы узнать, можно ли как-либо реализовать следующее:

Есть массив с частями условий, которые должны соблюдаться

```
$clauses=array(
    array(
        'clause_name'   => 'ext_dna_status',
        'clause_sign'   => '==',
        'clause_value'  => 0
    ),
    array(
        'clause_name'   => 'end_date',
        'clause_sign'   => '>=',
        'clause_value'  => '2017-07-20'
    )
);
```

Массив этот будет передаваться функции (пока не написана), которая должна будет проверить соблюдение всех условий, описанных в массиве, в массиве других данных. Отдельной переменной функции передаётся разделитесь частей условий - and, or. Универсальности от функции не требуется - она призвана просто сократить количество однотипного кода.

Например, на вход функция получает массив с данными (ниже) и разделитель `and`. Т.е. по сути для каждой части массива с данными нужно проверить каждое условие из массива с условиями -  (даты для наглядности я не переводил в unixtime) `if ($ext_dna_status==1 and $end_date>=2017-07-20)`.

```
$in=array(
    array(
        'ext_dna_status'    => 0,
        'end_date'          => '2017-07-20'
    ),
    array(
        'ext_dna_status'    => 1,
        'end_date'          => '2017-07-20'
    ),
    array(
        'ext_dna_status'    => 0,
        'end_date'          => '2017-07-25'
    )
);
```

Вопрос, как склеить части условий из массива так, чтобы они "сработали"? Можно перебирать все элементы массива с условиями и изменять значение переменной-флага, если условие выполняется, например. Но как части условия превратить в это самое условие? Т.е. **как сроку** вида `$clause=$clauses[0]['clause_name'].$clauses[0]['clause_sign'].$clauses[0]['clause_value'];` **обработать как условие**?

Comment: Операторов сравнения ограниченное количество http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php. Сделайте проверку `clause_sign` (в `switch`, например) и сравнивайте уже содержимое `['clause_value']` и элемент из `$in` в соответствующей ветке оператора `switch`.

Comment: Но если есть возможность из текста сделать переменную ${$str}, нельзя ли сделать так и с оператором сравнения?

Comment: Есть, конечно, функция `eval()` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.eval.php но пользоваться ей не рекомендуется.

Comment: @n.osennij мне понравилась ваша задачка, я её решил через создание массива функций на основе данных массива `$clauses`. Если интересно - выложу =)

Comment: @n.osennij ну и как обычно, есть уже готовая библиотека, позволяющая достигнуть вашей цели (давно хотел её попробовать, руки не доходили =)

Comment: @Visman спасибо за подсказку. Изучу

Comment: @АндрейМиндубаев Буду благодарен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Второе решение - использование пакета [`symfony/expression-language`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html)

Сначала нужно установить эту библиотеку через `composer require symfony/expression-language`

Решение задачи - четыре строки кода. Более универсальное решение, чем любой самописный велосипед.

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

use Symfony\Component\ExpressionLanguage\ExpressionLanguage;

$language = new ExpressionLanguage();
$condition = "ext_dna_status == 0 and end_date >= '2017-07-20'";
```

Здесь мы составляем выражение, которое нужно обработать и вычислить. Всем этим будет заниматься объект `$language`

Пример использования:

```
var_export([
    $language->evaluate($condition, [ 'ext_dna_status' => 0, 'end_date' => '2017-07-20' ]),
    $language->evaluate($condition, [ 'ext_dna_status' => 1, 'end_date' => '2017-07-20' ]),
    $language->evaluate($condition, [ 'ext_dna_status' => 0, 'end_date' => '2017-07-25' ]),
]);
```

Результат работы

```
array (
  0 => true,
  1 => false,
  2 => true,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Первое решение задачи - самописный велосипед

```
<?php

class Expression
{
    const CLUE_AND = "and";
    const CLUE_OR = "or";

    protected $clauses = array();

    public static function createInstance()
    {
        return new static();
    }

    public function add($name, $sign, $value)
    {
        switch ($sign) {
            case "==":
                $clause = function(array $data) use ($name, $value) {
                    return $data[$name] == $value;
                };
                break;
            case ">=":
                $clause = function(array $data) use ($name, $value) {
                    return $data[$name] >= $value;
                };
                break;
            default:
                $clause = function() {
                    return false;
                };
        }
        $this->clauses[] = $clause;

        return $this;
    }

    public function check(array $data, $clue)
    {
        if (!sizeof($this->clauses)) {
            return null;
        }

        if ($clue == self::CLUE_AND) {
            $check = true;
        } elseif ($clue == self::CLUE_OR) {
            $check = false;
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        foreach ($this->clauses as $clause) {
            $result = $clause($data);
            if ($clue == self::CLUE_AND && !$result) {
                $check = false;
                break;
            } elseif ($clue == self::CLUE_OR && $result) {
                $check = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        return $check;
    }
}
```

Здесь при вызове функции `add` в список добавляется новая функция, у которой только один аргумент: массив с данными. На выходе функция возвращает булевое значение. Также есть функция `check`, которая проходится по списку условий и в зависимости от разделителя and/or обрабывает и возвращает общий результат

Пример использования:

```
$expr = Expression::createInstance()
    ->add("ext_dna_status", "==", "0")
    ->add("end_date", ">=", "2017-07-20");

var_export([
    $expr->check([ 'ext_dna_status' => 0, 'end_date' => '2017-07-20' ], Expression::CLUE_AND),
    $expr->check([ 'ext_dna_status' => 1, 'end_date' => '2017-07-20' ], Expression::CLUE_AND),
    $expr->check([ 'ext_dna_status' => 0, 'end_date' => '2017-07-25' ], Expression::CLUE_AND),
]);
```

Работает только с `==` и `>=`, нужно расширять функционал =) Здесь мы создаём пустое логическое выражение, добавляем к нему условия и получаем результат работы:

```
array (
  0 => true,
  1 => false,
  2 => true,
)
```